# Receiving result in android

Tags: java, android

I am beginner to android..I Integrated qr scanner in my app..problem is I added qr scanner button in two fragment..for receiving result I added on activityResult method..In my mainactivity..Is any another method for receiving result in android Instead of OnactivityResult method..If not their I should I add multiple onActivityResult method In my Mainactivty..can anyOne help me..

```
below is the my code for onActivityresult
     @Override
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult scanResult =IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, 
                data);
    if (scanResult != null) {

        if (scanResult.getContents() == null) {

            Log.d("ScanFragment", "Cancelled scan");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, " " + scanResult.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

    } else {
        //result fragment
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    // }

}
```

Comment: handle result with multiple request code.

Comment: can send me a sample code

Comment: Go through the sample given [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html#StartActivity)

Answer (score 2):

```
static final int FRAGMENT_ONE_REQUEST = 1;  // The request code
static final int FRAGMENT_TWO_REQUEST = 2;  // The request code
```

then use this from fragment one

```
 startActivityForResult(intent, FRAGMENT_ONE_REQUEST);
```

then use this from fragment two

```
startActivityForResult(intent, FRAGMENT_TWO_REQUEST);
```

in each fragment

```
@Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
       //some code
         if (requestCode == FRAGMENT_ONE_REQUEST) {
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: bro how  can I use startActivityForResult in fragment..can you send me a full code

Comment: Why did you check requestCode in the first condition  ? You either check if this is OK then manage the request code OR you manage the request code and the resultCode for each but here, if you came from FRAGMENT_TWO, this won't work.

Comment: that was my bad. simple copy paste error. corrected! thanx! @AxelH

Comment: You are welcome, add the condition for Frag_two just to be complete and you have my vote.

Comment: see my full codebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                IntentIntegrator integrator  = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
                integrator.initiateScan();  this i added in fragment and onactivity result method i added in activity

Comment: yeah!. @pruthvireddy if this is working well then consider accepting answer! thanks!